# Integration for Thunderbird 5?

Tags: 11.04, thunderbird

Thunderbird 5 is a really good program but are there any plans to "integrate" it with 11.04 like Evolution is integrated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in 11.04, but coming in 11.10, Thunderbird 5 will be the default email client: http://ubuntulook.com/2011/07/07/ubuntu-11-10-uses-thunderbird-5-as-default-mail-client/

Comment: Bummer! I kinda figured for 11.10 though, Thanks.

Comment: @Rob Thunderbird is moving to a quick release cycle like Firefox is, it's likely you'll get a thunderbird update with some of the integration goodies at some point in 11.04